# How to query transaction history of a special kind of asset

Tags: horizon

When we issued our own asset, how to query transaction history of it?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply querying transactions and then filter them by asset type,
use the limit options for get more results if your users make a lot of different transactions in addition of what are you looking for and then write a function that  return a fixed number of past transactions , if it needed you can iterate the get request increasing limit until you can satisfy your history request

Comment: It seems there is no filter in stellar's native API, do you mean query all transaction to local and filter with yourself function?

Comment: yep, i'm doing this right now, but my accounts are pretty clean, my user uses only my asset and they're using stellar only for paying fees so in my scenario